# Logging to a single file in a project that spawns and destroys multiple child processes?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, logging, process

The way the current logging works is we're using Winston to log to a file using the PID as part of the filename, as a result we end up with 10,000+ log files per day (a lot of processes are created and destroyed).

I was thinking of having a single socket server where log calls are sent and handles logging everything from all processes to a single file per type of log level. However, I've read that this could cause a bottleneck?

Just looking for some guidance, I've done some searching but can't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Maybe you should add details, it's hard to answer you with precision. One thing though, how do you plan to handle concurrent access to the "single file per type of log level" if different processes try to write at the same time?

Comment: I was planning on using a queue for each log level, when a process sends a log request it gets added to the back of the queue. Logs then get written to the corresponding file one at a time from the front of the queue.

What other details would be good?

Comment: That seems fine, now where do you expect "that this could cause a bottleneck"? Additionnally, it could be useful to know where you read it

Comment: The answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339732/node-js-multiprocess-logging

I don't fully understand the answer, but also don't want to use that package.